# Integrating Perl and Oracle Advanced Queuing

Tags: perl, oracle, messaging, advanced-queuing

Is there any way to listen to an Oracle AQ using a Perl process as the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Introduction to Oracle Advanced Queuing](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/9i/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm#65422) states that you can interface to it through "Internet access using HTTP, HTTPS, and SMTP" so it should be straightforward to do that using a Perl script.